Do doc-strings affect performance in GDScript?
Apparently in Python, doc-strings do slow down programs, at least that's what I've been reading in other questions... but what about GDScript? Should I just use # instead?


This looks like a question you could answer empirically by profiling the same script with docstrings and again with the docstrings removed. Do you measure any significant performance difference between the two cases when you try that?

@DMGregory well ofcourse I'd have to add hundreds of lines of doc sring to every single script to even see it budge a notch in performance, I just began wirintg the docs for my game now... less than 100 lines in
